# New Tactics for Acquiring Link Backs

Tags: seo, search-engine

As all SEOs know that google is trying its very best to kill SEO and linkbacks are quite a difficult task now. Although content is the key but my boss is still possessed with linkbacks. I can not do directory posting, link exchange, paid linking, web 2.0 and blog commenting as they are spam now. I do not see what other choice i have except forum posting and article posting. Can someone suggest new method to acquire link backs ? I know almost all traditional methods so don't say press release or etc. If you really have something out of the box or not very much common please share.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I do not understand. How it is off topic. It is an SEO quesiton and by the way i created this topic

Comment: Click on the SEO tag and read it

Comment: I already have read. This question is related to SEO

Comment: You did not read it. If you did you would have seen it said that SEO is off-topic at this website.

Comment: Oh yeah now i understand. Such a pity. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Google isn't killing SEO, they trying to banish practices that your boss is so intent on doing.

If you want to build a quality reputation - you need to start creating genuine and unique content aimed at your target audience. Research your market, offer your visitors information they want to read and share. Make sure what you create is geared towards Google.

**Make it relevant, current, accurate and engaging.**

Of course, this all takes time and considerable effort - if you or your boss can't devote the time needed, or at least employ someone to do it for you... the business is going to suffer online.

Comment: Very much agree with you but you can not take decision against your boss will.

Answer (score -1):

Buy the links. The majority of online marketing agencies do this as the primary way to increase Google rank.

Or go the natural way and produce so much fine content people will naturally share it.

Comment: Your second suggestion is good, but I cannot get behind your first suggestion. Google seeks to give people relevant content, and so if they discover that you're just buying links with no good content (and thus are doing a disservice to their users), they may penalize you.

Comment: Paid links are spam and fall under unnatural link. Company's website can get penalized